# Check if cart have active subscriptions in YITH WooCommerce Subscription Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, subscriptions

I am using YITH WooCommerce Subscription and I want to check if in my cart has subscription I want to disable one of my payment gateway. How could I do ?

I already try this code but this is doesn't work.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_gateways', 1);
function filter_gateways( $gateways ){

    if (has_woocommerce_subscription('','','active')) {
        unset( $gateways['pin_payments'] );
    }
    return $gateways; 
}

function has_woocommerce_subscription($the_user_id, $the_product_id, $the_status) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (empty($the_user_id)) {
        $the_user_id = $current_user->ID;
    }
    if (WC_Subscriptions_Manager::user_has_subscription( $the_user_id, $the_product_id, $the_status)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 questions, one is active subscription that you can test via this function:

```
    function CheckSubscriptionByEmail($email) { 

        // getting all the records of the user by email for the subscription
        $subscriptions = get_posts( array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_type'   => 'ywsbs_subscription', // Subscription post type
            'orderby' => 'post_date', // ordered by date
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_billing_email', //additional fields being used to get the data
                'value' => $email,
                'compare' => '='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => '_status',
                'value' => 'active', //active subscriptions
                'compare' => '='
            ))
        ) );

        // check if user has any active subscription
        foreach ( $subscriptions as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
            $nextdue = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), '_payment_due_date',true);
            $current_date = date("Y-m-d");
            $date_to_compare = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($nextdue)); 
            if (strtotime($date_to_compare) > strtotime($current_date)) {
                echo "active"; //returns active 
                break;
            }
        endforeach; 
        wp_reset_postdata();

    }
```

Refernece and Explanation at:
https://makersbyte.com/check-active-subscriptions-using-yith-woocommerce/

If you want to just test all the active subcriptions then change in above function the following:

```
        $subscriptions = get_posts( array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_type'   => 'ywsbs_subscription', // Subscription post type
            'orderby' => 'post_date', // ordered by date
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_status',
                'value' => 'active', //active subscriptions
                'compare' => '='
            ))
        ) );
```

Once you have the list of active subscription, it be fairly straight and simple to disable them if needed.

Payment Gateway, simply goto Woocommerce -> Checkout > All payment gateways are listed in it. Use it to disable.